# On-premise Mobile Device Management solution for Android

Tags: android, security, remote-access, mobile

I'm looking for a **Mobile Device Management solution** that can be **deployed** on my **own servers**. Cloud-based solutions are strictly NOT required.

Please enlist such solutions which can cater at-least following features:

- Restricted Access to Device Settings (Only some of the settings
  should be available to user)
- Restricted access to system and 3rd-party apps
- Auto-launch of an app on device launch VPN connectivity setup on
  device start / app launch. (The app won't run without VPN access, so
  the system should automatically connect/reconnect to VPN)
- Auto-update of allowed apps remotely (from management/admin portal)
- Enable/Disable device remotely